# TensorFlow fails to convert string to number

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm building a neural network that is supposed to classify input words in some way. Without going into much detail on the network itself, I was looking for a way to convert my input words to an integer format, in order to use TensorFlow's `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(...)` for input encoding.

I noticed that `tf.string_to_number()` exists, so I tried using that, but it failed. First I thought it was related to what I'm doing in my network, but even when doing something like

```
import tensorflow as tf
s = tf.string_to_number("TEST", out_type=tf.int32)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(s)
```

in a python console, I get the same error of

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: 
StringToNumberOp could not correctly convert string: TEST
```

I also tried creating a `tf.constant("TEST", dtype=tf.string)` first and passing that on to `tf.string_to_number()` and ran this test code on a webserver to make sure it wasn't related to my setup, but with the same result.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

You are missing the purpose of `string_to_number` it is supposed to convert a number, represented as string, to the numerical type, like `tf.string_to_number('1')`, it is not "one hot encoder" for strings (how would it be able to figure out the size in the vocab in the first place?)

There is a nice tutorial in tensorflow itself which shows how to train embedding models in [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) which goes through everything, starting with data reading and ending with full embedding using the lookup op.

Comment: Makes sense. I thought it was supposed to generate a number based on the characters in the string or something. The tutorial corresponding to that file assumes the words are already integerized, but I'll have to write that code myself then. I'll look into their implementation. Thanks!

Comment: well this is false. Text8, that is used in the code I referenced is a raw text and the code converts it, thus you do not have to write it yourself.